# error: no matching function for call to ‘_3DVec::_3DVec()’

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I can't get this constructor right (`RMatrix.class.h`) :

```
RMatrix (_3DVec& Wup, _3DVec& Out, double Spin) {
    // ...
}
```

My main file has :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "classes/Color.class.h"
#include "classes/Vector.class.h"
#include "classes/RMatrix.class.h"

int main () {
    // ...
}
```

`_3DVec` is defined defined in `Vector.class.h` and included before the RMatrix file.

Compiler throws : `error: no matching function for call to ‘_3DVec::_3DVec()’`.

`RMatrix` file code :

```
class RMatrix {

private:

    _3DVec right;
    _3DVec up;
    _3DVec out;
    double spin;
    double MData[16];


public:

    RMatrix (_3DVec& Wup, _3DVec& Out, double Spin) {
        // stuff...
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you haven't defined a default-constructor. Show us the `RMatrix.h` file and show us the code where you construct the `RMaxtrix` instance.

Comment: I'm not constructing any RMatrix instance yet.

Comment: @Julien: It doesn't matter whether you are actually constructing it or not. You wrote `RMatrix` constructor, which makes an attempt to implicitly call `_3DVec`'s default constructor. The compiler cannot compile this code since the required default constructor does not exist. You have to rewrite `RMatrix` constructor so that it does not make any attempts to default-construct `_3DVec`.

Comment: Why does the same kind of instantiation doesn't raise an error when done inside the _3DVec class (talking _3DVec constructors) ?

Comment: For example : `_3DVec (const _3DVec& vertexFrom, const _3DVec& vertexTo) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that somewhere in your code the default constructor of `_3DVec` class is needed. And class `_3DVec` does not have a default constructor. Hence the error.

In the code you posted `RMatrix` members `right`, `up` and `out` are default-constructed by `RMatrix` constructor. So, this is exactly where the default constructor is required.

I could make a guess that constructor parameters are supposed to be used as initializers to your vectors, as in

```
 RMatrix (_3DVec& Wup, _3DVec& Out, double Spin) : up(Wup), out(Out) {
    // stuff...
 }
```

The above takes care of `up` and `out` by copy-constructing `up` and `out`, but that still leaves your `right` default-constructed. And that is still a guess. Only you know how what your class members are supposed to be initialized with.

P.S. Note also that in C++ language global-namespace names that begin with `_` are reserved to implementation. You are not allowed to use such names in global namespace.

Comment: Compiler says the error is at the exact line where the RMatrix constructor is. I think I get it now thanks.

Comment: I want to pass _3DVec's into the constructor of the matrix. Why do I need a default constructor for that ?

Comment: @Julien: That's great. But the way it is written now, you have to *copy* constructor parameters into class members. My example above shows how to copy them using the copy-constructor. However, that covers `up` and `out` only. I have no idea what you were planning to do with `up`.

Comment: Correction: I have no idea what you were planning to do with `right`.

Comment: I could resolve the issue by adding an empty `_3DVec () {}` constructor in my vector class.

Comment: @Julien; Well, yes, that will resolve the issue. You added the missing constructor. But that does not answer the question of why it wasn't there in the first place. Simply forgotten? Or was it by design? Are you the author of `_3DVec` class or someone else?

Comment: Im the author and no it's not by design. I simply didn't know I needed such a constructor. I juste started writing c++.